# Bigquery custom schedule at 3 specific time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I am trying to create scheduled query on bigquery at 3 specific time
at 07:00, 14:00, 17:00 everyday.

I tried looking for custom schedule syntax and came across this documentation
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?hl=en_GB#the_schedule_format

but haven't found solution for daily at 3 specific time. Do I have to create 3 separate scheduled query for this or is there any syntax to set daily with 3 specific time?

Any answers are appreciated!

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query) public documentation that google provides, you can create custom scheduled queries into BigQuery based on an hourly basis, so for your case you could create a custom scheduled query that runs at 07:00, 14:00 and 17:00 without a problem.

Edit: Based on some research I did, there're two things that I would recommend you, that you make your script to run at those hours or you could do a job for every time you want to run your query, take below approach as an example.

```
every Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun 07:00
every Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun 14:00
every Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun 17:00
```

Comment: based on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?hl=en_GB#the_schedule_format , the syntax for setting up scheduled query, the closest I can get is 'everyday 07:00', haven't found how to set 3 specific hour simultaneously

Comment: I edited my response, hope it helps you @NadiaNoversega